# How can I stop my print bed tape from sticking to the filament?

Tags: abs, filament, maintenance

I made a test print for a small gear (~ 1.5 inches in diameter) a few months ago, with a hole through the center. On the first try, the filament (ABS) fused to the print bed, meaning that I had to spend ten minutes scraping off material to loosen it. One solution to this is to use painter's tape spread across the print bed.

This yielded a good print during the next run. The problem with this method was that some of the tape subsequently fused to the backside of the gear; it was so tight that I had to discard the prototype. Multiple varieties of tape made no difference.

Is there a way to continue using this tape without having it fuse to the filament?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can highly depend on the slicer you are using. Some software such as Makerware and Slic3r allow you to adjust the settings for the first raft/part layers. I might suggest adjusting this "Z0" point to about 1/4-1/2 of your layer height. Essentially the first layer (or two) will not adhere as well.

This is just one suggestion of many solutions. Here are some other variables I could think of off-hand:

- Type of build plate tape (ie masking, painters, kapton, etc.)
- Type of material. I've noticed that PLA is very stubborn if you let the part completely cool after printing and that it's much easier to remove the part from the build plate/raft right after it's complete.
- Type of build plate. Are you applying too much heat (if you have a heated bp) for the material such as PLA?
- Try lowering your layer height. This will ensure that each strand does not have too much surface area and therefore less chance that it will create a vacuum affect with the build plate. This can, however, result in a worse surface finish.

Comment: Note that if you do attempt to remove a "warm" print, I would make sure you use a tool (i.e. a spatula or similar) as opposed to your hand

Answer (score 1):

My very first thought was you didn't re-calibrate your Z0 after adding the blue tape. It sounds like the print head was too close to the print bed to begin with, and adding the blue tape just made it that much worse.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I do to  keep it from sticking to the tape. Is to add glue from a glue stick down on the building pad in an even coat on top of the tape.