# How to remove exess filament from bed after removing model

Tags: pla, heated-bed, post-processing

Recently got an Anycubic I3 Mega Printer and I've been playing with what it can do, but after a model is done it leaves residue on the build plate behind that is bugging me. Do I NEED to remove it? If so, how? Thanks! (I'm using PLA if that matters)

My Problem:

[image: Residue left on build plate]

Comment: My gut check is "yes", mainly because some of it will come off with a new print. If you're using black next, the white filament will then leave splotches on your next print. The reason I'm not leaving an answer is ... I really don't know how to get it off of a bed which isn't aluminum (like mine) where you'd just use a scraper to clean it up. WIth any kind of surface which can be damaged (like I'm assuming yours can), I really don't know the best way to clean them up. Just thinking about it, acetone may work to clean up PLA, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Ok, If I do leave it on, will it affect future prints outside of leaving splotches?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 PLA does not dissolve in acetone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I best clean the print bed after a print?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/215/how-can-i-best-clean-the-print-bed-after-a-print)

Comment: This usually doesn't happen on an Ultrabase, except you did not use it properly. It is essential that you wait until the Ultrabase is cooled down before removing the object. If cooled to room temperature the object can be removed very easily. If not material will stay behind and jam the "pores" of the special surface. Use isopropyl alcohol to clean it.

Comment: @KlausD. This is actually one of the best answers I've gotten so far, are you sure isopropyl alcohol will not damage the bed?

Comment: Not at all, in problematic cases you can even go one step further and use acetone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove it because it can and will affect the quality of future prints. Residue can mix up with new filament and create a ugly of colors and also prevent adhesion in places, thus potentially ruining your next print.

You have several solutions to clean up the bed:

- Scrape it off: usually works, but you risk chipping the surface if you're not careful or if you stumble upon a bit of residue that is stubborn and you need to apply strength to get rid of it. I think a scraper is included with the printer.
- Sponge and soap: Since the bed cannot be removed, as far as I can tell, you'll need to make sure that the sponge isn't dripping or put towel paper around to avoid damaging the components below, including the heating unit. Rub it gently on the residue until it soften and detaches. It might take a bit to work.
- [Yellow glass cleaner from Karcher](https://www.kaercher.com/fr/home-garden/produits-de-nettoyage-et-d-entretien/reinigungs-pflegemittel/batterie-pour-nettoyeur-de-vitres/nettoyant-vitres/nettoyant-vitres-concentre-62953020.html): my favourite, the one I use on my printer and it never failed me. Spray it on a cloth or something, and rub it on the bed until the residue softens and detaches. It might take a bit to work, but you don't run the risk of dripping liquid on any component, and it works way better than soap and without the risk of chipping the bed like when you use a scraper.

Comment: Thank you! You say that you use the yellow glass cleaner, what printer do you own?

Comment: @UltraGamer I have an Ultimaker 3 Extended.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that while there are good reasons for removing it, leaving it in place probably won't affect the print too much. If you don't care about how the bottom layer looks, it probably won't hurt.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden The main hurt that this kind of residue does is prevent good bed adhesion. And since it's not always apparent right away, you run the risk of having your print pop out in part or completely several hours into it, ruining it and forcing you to start again, not to mention wasting time and material. Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have had moderate success with a product called [Goo Gone](https://googone.com) (don't laugh). It quite remarkably lifts off any number of "sticky" items from various surfaces.

I work with PLA filament that is very hard and stubborn to remove from any surface.

I own a FlashForge Adventurer 3 that appears to have a carbon fiber build plate. Nothing, except a #11 XActo blade, can harm that.

Comment: Good Gone contains d-Limonene which dissolves HIPS, it doesn't dissolve PLA, how does it remove the stuck PLA?